# Replay mouse movement with javascript

Tags: javascript, mousemove, replay

I recently asked a question about mouse RECORDING. Now I need to figure out how to REPLAY it.

Recent question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8129723/record-mouse-movement-with-javascript

I will use PHP to make an identical copy of the current page, then I will insert the replay script in it. The script will add and move araound an absolut posisioned image acording to multiple x and y cordinates, in relation to time (to illustrate the mousemovement).

Are there any good methods (better then below) to replay mulitple mousemovements?

```
<input style="width:100%" type="text" name="onlyforstackoverflow1" value="0" size="4"><br>
<input style="width:100%" type="text" name="onlyforstackoverflow2" value="0" size="4">



<script>

// I want this (a very long array with x-cordinates, y-cordinates and time from pageload)

var very_long_array = [1,2,1000,2,22,2000,3,33,3645,4,44,3456];

// To become the same as this

setTimeout("document.Show.onlyforstackoverflow1.value = 1;document.Show.onlyforstackoverflow2.value = 11;",100)
setTimeout("document.Show.onlyforstackoverflow1.value = 2;document.Show.onlyforstackoverflow2.value = 22;",200)
setTimeout("document.Show.onlyforstackoverflow1.value = 3;document.Show.onlyforstackoverflow2.value = 33;",364)
setTimeout("document.Show.onlyforstackoverflow1.value = 4;document.Show.onlyforstackoverflow2.value = 44;",453)


// in the real script it will be moving around an image instead...

</script>
```

Comment: This is very useful for me...but I also want to integrate pause and resume functionality for replay. I have looked for it but answers are only available for setTimeout cases, not for setTimeout inside recursive function.So can you put some light on how to accomplish it.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var dataList = [ 1, 2, 1000, 2, 22, 2000 ], // the long big array 
    preTime = 0;

function run() {
    var parts = dataList.splice( 0, 3 ), // after splice, dataList will be auto updated
        nowTime;

    if ( parts.length ==  3 ) {
         nowTime = parts[ 2 ];

         setTimeout( function() {
             replay( parts[ 0 ], parts[ 1 ] ); // x = parts[ 0 ], y = parts[ 1 ]

             preTime = nowTime;
             // continue run next replay
             run();
         }, nowTime - preTime );
    } 
}

function replay( x, y ) {
    // do something with x, y;
    // document.Show.onlyforstackoverflow1.value = x;
    // document.Show.onlyforstackoverflow2.value = y;
}

// start
run();
```

Just use setTimeout to do the task, you needn't write every task as a statement :-)

Comment: This is very useful for me...but I also want to integrate pause and resume functionality for replay. I have looked for it but answers are only available for setTimeout cases, not for setTimeout inside recursive function.So can you put some light on how to accomplish it.Thanks in advance